# conditional probability Bayes Rule

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

A digital communications system consists of transmitter and a receiver. During each short transmission interval the transmitter sends a signal which is to be interpreted as A zero, or it sends a different signal which is to be interpreted as a  one. At the end of each interval, the receiver makes its best guess at what was transmitted.

Consider the events:

> $T_0$ = {transmitter sends 0},   $R_0$ = {receiver concludes that a 0 was sent}
>
> $T_1$ = {transmitter sends 1},   $R_1$ = {receiver concludes that a 1 was sent}

Assume that: $\mathsf P(R_0\mid T_0)=0.99,\\ 
            \mathsf P(R_1\mid T_1)=0.98,\\ 
            \mathsf P(T_1)=0.5$

Find:

(a) the probability of A transmission error given $R_1$;

(b) the overall probability of a transmission error;

(c) Repeat (a) and (b) assuming $\mathsf P(T_1)=0.8$ instead of $0.5$

Comment: What work have you done so far?

Comment: You will receive better feedback if you show your own efforts, to indicate exactly what about the question is causing you trouble.

Answer (score 0):

To get you started

> (a) the probability of A transmission error given $R_1$  ;

Find: $\mathsf P(T_0\mid R_1)$

> (b) the overall probability of a transmission error;

Find: $\mathsf P((T_1\cap R_0) \cup (T_0\cap R_1))$